# Spring controller add attribute to any request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, model

I need to show logged user name on any page. Is it possible to use only 1 method that will be called on any request and will add name attribute to model?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have add `spring-security` tag in your question,so if you want to show logged user at any page,the best choice is using `spring-security`.

First,add the below declaration in your jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

Then in your jsp page we can use `<sec:authentication property="name"/>` to show the logged in user at any page.

Comment: I did it with Thymeleaf, but html element stays empty. And if I'll need to add an additional information like last online or something else, that UserDetails class doesn't have?

Comment: no,but you need to check if spring secure tag can work on Thymeleaf

Comment: this code:
"Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span>"
from official documentation https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html
doesn't work, I have only "Logged user:" text, without username

Comment: still doesn't work, and your first code is for jsp, second (with <span></span>) is for Thymeleaf

Comment: @VadymBorys have you added the related jars `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3`? It's weird,`<span sec:authentication="name"></span>` should work,don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
Either you store the username in the Session (setRequestAtrributes) or you create a filterchain which reads the username by the auth-token/authentication. Depending on where you decide which user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **Servlet Filter** as below which is adding userName into **response Header**.

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();

        if(session !=null&& session.getAttribute("username")!=null){
            httpServletResponse.addHeader("username",httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("username").toString() );
        }
}
```

And use userName from response in your UI.